# How pgpool-II getting node information?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-13, pgpool

I want to know where from pgpool getting those node information. I am getting node information using below command but unable to find from where it is getting those data. Is there any database or table or function for pgpool from where it is getting those information. Is here anyone can help me on this?

```
SHOW pool_nodes;
```

[image: pgpool node information]

Answer (score 1):

Pgpool-II intercept this(i.e SHOW) query and return this information. It is not store in database are table, Pgpool-II itself of this information.